# Poisson quantization vs quantization in atomic physics

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-mechanics, poisson-geometry

Is it possible to interpret quantization in atomic physics ( e.g. the quantization condition in hydrogen atom stated as exponential decay of wave functions at infinity and analogously for n-electron atoms) as Poisson quantization (e.g. in the sense of Kontsevich, or some other version)?

EDIT: As per answer below, some clarification. Wave functions of hydrogen are confluent hypergeometric functions. They have essential singularity at infinity and quantization is a statement about position of Stokes lines. There is a lot of relationship between Stokes structure, Poisson manifolds, quantum groups, Frobenius maifolds, etc. and hypergeometric functions, as e.g. in Xu Toledano-Laredo https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.10298 , Dubrovin, https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.04808 , Boalch,https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1050 , Bridgeland,...  My question is: is it possible to identify Poisson manifold, Stokes data, and perhaps some additional structure  so that it is possible to interpret the wave functions and the quantization condition precisely as quantization in these terms?

Comment: You are comfortable with the standard deformation quantization of the [Hydrogen atom in trivial phase space](https://doi.org/10.1080/00268978200100752), no?

Answer (score 1):

Atomic physics typically is concerned with a trivial phase space ($\mathbb{R}^6$), rather than the nontrivial Poisson manifolds considered in Poisson quantization. With this simplification the atomic quantization condition (the Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization rule) has been obtained by [deformation quantization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/deformation+quantization) in
[Moyal star product approach to the Bohr-Sommerfeld approximation](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0409039) (2005).

Comment: Out of curiosity: do you have a reference for a worked-out example of an actual physical system being quantized using the full machinery of Poisson quantization? I think I have never seen a quantum-mechanical system with constraints that would make its phase space nontrivial.

Comment: Magnetic monopoles have been considered in this context, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.02845